# What could I do to recover javamail Folder when a "Socket is closed" is received?

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-mail

I have a simple server which listen for incoming email messages from more than one folder, in this scenario for example it is listening from 2 folders.
I have two threads x folder which keep alive the connection.

I had a situation where only one folder has received a "socket is closed", while the other was alive, I would have expected that if connection (with Store?) had been closed then the other folder too has thrown exception.

Follows stacktrace:

```
"javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1064)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:973)
        at ....MyClass.open(MyClass.java:112)
        at ....MyClass$MyClassSynchThread.run(MyClass.java:668)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:401)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.select(IMAPProtocol.java:1184)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1030)
        ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Each open folder gets a separate connection.  When you get the exception, close the folder and reopen it.

Comment: Are you saying that an open call is not enough? Before it should I call close?
As you can see in logs I'm opening folder, then in above logs it is not visible but I'm opening it because I've just received a FolderClosedException....so I'm really don't understanding why should I close a Folder in that state.
Please Bill, could you explain that better? Thanks as always

Comment: The close call probably isn't necessary.  I think it only determines whether you get a FolderClosedException or IllegalStateException when you call another method on a folder that has been closed; the former occurs when the folder is closed by the server and the latter occurs when the folder is closed by the client.

Comment: In summary, what should I do to restore connection?
If close is not necessary and if the open call throws SocketException, what  is left to do?

I'm thinking to close and reopen Store, but in this way I will invalidate the other "live" Folders bound to the same Store, is it true?
Thx

Comment: You should close and reopen the Folder that failed.  If you close the Store, it will close all the open Folders.